# Copy files *without* taking ownership

Tags: windows-7, backup, ntfs

I'm manually backing up data off a hard drive that has XP installed on it, because I suspect the drive is failing. I want to copy the files, but I *don't* want to change the owner (or any permissions) on the original drive, to be able to do so.  Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Turns out [Robocopy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145.aspx) can do this incredibly easily.  Simply include the `/B` option on your command line, to copy files in Backup mode.  This requires that you run as Administrator.

My command line:

```
robocopy /MIR /B "E:\Documents and Settings" "C:\DeadDriveBackup\Documents and Settings"
```

Comment: That's exactly the way. Some backup tools can also do this, but robocopy is the simplest option.

Comment: `/COPYALL` option is useful if you need the exact same permissions on the target files/directories.

Answer (score 8):

The given answer did not work for me; this did.

Robocopy has a `/COPY` argument used to specify which parts of files to copy. Available to copy are **d**ata, **a**ttributes, **t**imestamps, **s**ecurity information (NTFS ACLs), **o**wnership information, and a**u**diting information. If you're looking to copy everything in one directory to another perfectly, use this:

```
robocopy /E /B /COPYALL "C:\One" "C:\Two"
```

Let's analyse:

- `/E` copies all files, including empty directories. This works like `/MIR`, but *doesn't delete anything in the destination*.
- `/B` copies in "backup mode", giving Robocopy the permission to overwrite ACLs (file permissions).
- `/COPYALL` is an alias to `/COPY:DATSOU`, which copies all file data, including file ownership and permission (ACL) data.

#### Are you copying a user profile?

I was, and there are some extra caveats. Default Windows user profiles contain directory junction loops, and Robocopy cannot be configured to create new junctions rather than following them. The above Robocopy command will fail and create difficult-to-remove directory trees, so use this command which will exclude junctions.

```
robocopy /E /B /COPYALL /XJ "C:\One" "C:\Two"
```

For compatibility you should probably recreate the default directory junctions in a user profile:

```
mklink /J "Application Data" "AppData\Roaming"
mklink /J "Cookies" "AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCookies"
mklink /J "Local Settings" "AppData\Local"
mklink /J "My Documents" "Documents"
mklink /J "NetHood" "AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts"
mklink /J "PrintHood" "AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Printer Shortcuts"
mklink /J "Recent" "AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent"
mklink /J "SendTo" "AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo"
mklink /J "Start Menu" "AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu"
mklink /J "Templates" "AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Templates"
attrib /L +S +H +I "Application Data"
attrib /L +S +H +I "Cookies"
attrib /L +S +H +I "Local Settings"
attrib /L +S +H +I "My Documents"
attrib /L +S +H +I "NetHood"
attrib /L +S +H +I "PrintHood"
attrib /L +S +H +I "Recent"
attrib /L +S +H +I "SendTo"
attrib /L +S +H +I "Start Menu"
attrib /L +S +H +I "Templates"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would boot a live CD like [Parted Magic](https://partedmagic.com/) and use something like [GNU ddrescue](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/) to image the drive.

If you really only want some of the files, you can always copy just the files you want - by default NTFS partitions should be mounted read-only, so there's no possibility to accidentally change anything.

Comment: Good advice. I typically boot to [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) for making hard drive images. In this case though, I only have the hard drive, connected via a USB2 external adapter.

Comment: If a drive could be failing it's usually a bad idea to write anything to it - I think Windows does this automatically (at least, Windows XP used to do things like leaving thumbs.db files everywhere, I don't know what kind of caches 7 or 8 uses). I'm not sure exactly how to tell Windows to mount a newly-connected USB drive read-only, so I tend to avoid it when dealing with suspect drives. (Also, I think the error messages tend to be less informative, and distros like Clonezilla and Parted Magic tend to have better built-in tools...)